# Proportion of Mass? Checking if this question is ok

Tags: support

I thought I better run this past the meta before asking it on the main site.

I've been directed here from Biology.SE regarding good scientific language, see the question below.

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/43058/proportion-of-mass

Does this fall under "Word choice and usage." and so is ok to ask?

Comment: I'd like to commend you for thinking about the question before posting, so here's my opinion on the underlying question even if it turns out to be off-topic on EL&U: *mass* is fine. Once you've chosen the term, you can say 20% *by mass* or 20% *by volume*, etc. for clarity.

Comment: Thats very helpful.

Comment: I think this is a question about language purely for the technical audience, which would know much better than a general language English site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, the problem with this question is that there are many answers that could conceivably work. See the first bullet point in "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)", namely, *every answer is equally valid*.

People could respond with *weight*, *mass*, *mols*, *volume*, or just about any kind of measurement, and it could be acceptable.

On the other hand, if you narrowed it down to *mass* (or the definition of *mass*), then you've answered your own question and don't need to ask it.